# Exchange each 100 in a dataframe for another value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file without headers and several values. I only want to exchange each 100 in the file for a 20.

I don't know if it would work with an if condition. I know i can select each 100 with the following code

`df[df,iloc[:,:== 100]` but i don't know how to only exchange each 100 for another value

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you're looking to do? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe, and `100` is the value you want to replace with `20`. I would do:

`df = df.replace(to_replace=100, value=20)`

As shown in the [guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: Yes thanks, that works. Do you know how i could replace all values of 100 with the value in the row in front of them. I only know bfill and ffill, which would replace the 100 with the value in the column, but is there the same principle for this with the cell right and left to them?

Comment: You can know the position of a given value by doing `df.loc[df[target_column] == 100].index[target_row]`, then you can reassign the value in the found position to the one of the following column by simply adding an offset.